# How to move some software's folder from appdata folder?

Tags: windows-7

I do not want to change the location of appdata.

I want, for example, change the location of firefox folder in appdata to another drive. There

are also other software that I want to move their folders out of appdata.

I use windows 7.

Comment: I see. What does your own research suggest you can do? You can't do what you want for just a few items/directories etc

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to move a single folders location unless the application allows this. Firefox as far as I'm aware does allow this though.

Read [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_profile_folder#Modify_profiles.ini_to_point_to_the_new_location_-_Advanced):

> Modify profiles.ini to point to the new location - Advanced Firefox,
>   Thunderbird and SeaMonkey 2 Note: This method does not apply to
>   Mozilla Suite/SeaMonkey 1.x, which uses a different system for keeping
>   track of profiles. Firefox, Thunderbird, or SeaMonkey 2 should already
>   be installed on the computer where you are moving the profile and a
>   profile folder and profiles.ini file should already exist. This method
>   is recommended for advanced users only since it can be tough to
>   troubleshoot. Mozilla applications can be very finicky about the
>   contents of the profiles.ini file. They normally do not ignore bad
>   entries, regardless of their position in the file. Create a new, empty
>   folder in the desired profile location with the name you wish to use
>   for the new profile, for example,
>   D:\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\newprofile Copy the entire contents of the
>   profile folder you are moving into the new profile folder you just
>   created. If you copied the old profile from a CD, remove the
>   write-protection from the copied files. Find the profiles.ini file (it
>   will be located in the default profile folder path) and open it in a
>   text editor. (Optional) Change the "Name=" line to the name of the new
>   profile folder you created, e.g., Name=newprofile Change
>   "IsRelative=1" to "IsRelative=0" (non-relative/full path) Change the
>   "Path=" line to the actual location of the new profile folder, e.g.,
>   Path=D:\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\newprofile. If you're using Windows
>   non-relative paths use back slashes while relative paths use forward
>   slashes so you may need to change the direction of the slashes too. If
>   you are moving a profile from its default location, the original
>   profile folder can now be removed. If you're using Thunderbird, check
>   that you can see the folders for each account. If they're missing, use
>   the browse button for the local directory in Tools -> Account Settings
>   -> Server Settings and Tools -> Account Settings -> Local Folders to specify the correct account and mail directories. Caution: Incorrect
>   editing of the "profiles.ini" file can cause a "already running but is
>   not responding" error if the profile cannot be found (bug 278860).

This needs to be application specific, you may also want to look at portable editions of software that are designed to be installed in USB devices, essentially not using any system properties but saving everything in their own files.

http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable

Edit:
You can also use [hard links](https://superuser.com/questions/746325/how-to-create-a-hard-link-in-windows-using-mklink-command).